# Undefined Error in Type Script

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to Type Script and i am Trying to convert a small piece of javascript code to typescript & getting an error: typeError list[i] is undefined.
**Here is my Actual js:**

```
function handleDragStart(e) {
  this.style.opacity = '0.4';  // this / e.target is the source node.
}

var cols = document.querySelectorAll('#columns .column');
[].forEach.call(cols, function(col) {
  col.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
});
```

**Here My Tried fiddle** 
https://jsfiddle.net/hahkarthick/8cwcb970/3/

Answer (score 3):

Use i directly instead of list[i].

Also you will have to pass function name instead of false in below code.

```
i.addEventListener("dragstart", false);
```

Full code :-

```
    class col {
  itrate(): any {
    let list: any = document.querySelectorAll("#columns .column");
    let i:any;
    for ( i of list) {
        console.log(i);
      console.log(list[i]);
      i.addEventListener("dragstart", this.dragStart);
    }
  }
  dragStart(event): any{
    console.log(event);
  }
}
let colz: any = new col();
colz.itrate();
```

Fiddle Link :- [working code](https://jsfiddle.net/8cwcb970/4/)

Comment: Ya i Tried That also and Getting Error: Argument 2 of EventTarget.addEventListener is not an object.

Comment: Now Getting Reference Error: i is not defined

Comment: @HarishKarthick Check again actually it is due to line i.addEventListener("dragstart", false); added above the code.

Comment: @HarishKarthick I have added js fiddle link also.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `for of`, your `i` is the current item, not it's index. So you just need to use `i`, not `list[i]`.

Your function need to look like this.

```
itrate(): any {
   let list: any = document.querySelectorAll("#columns .column");
   for (let i of list) {
     console.log(i);
     i.addEventListener("dragstart", false);
   }
}
```

One more thing, you will get an error because the second parameter of `addEventListener` must be a function. Pass a function into.

Comment: Thanks For You Help and Can you suggest me how to archive that @SurenSrapyan

Comment: @SurenSrapyan rejecting an edit with a working fiddle was is a little weird though, but whatever.

Comment: OP is working with `dragstart`, not just showing alert

Comment: @SurenSrapyan He does not in his fiddle. But I guess you have not had a look at it.